# ASP .NET - Como acceder a las propiedades de un dropdownList dinamico

Tags: asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podria decir que estoy haciendo mal? :C Trato de llenar dos DropDownList dinamicamente con fechas, pero me sucede esto... Por su atención gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba agregando este codigo en metodo Load del code behind

```
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {

         //Create datasource seria un metodo que retorna una lista de datos
        dFechaCierre.DataSource = CreateDataSource();

        //Aca iria el nombre del campo para usar en el id 
        dFechaCierre.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";

        //Aca iria el nombre del campo para usar en el value 
        dFechaCierre.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";


        dFechaCierre.DataBind();


        dFechaCierre.SelectedIndex = 0;

     }
```

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero primero el OP debería mejorar su pregunta acorde a [ask], pues las imágenes salvo que sea necesario no se deben usar; el puede editar y agregar el código como texto pues así es poco legible.